# Falied to create new custom object using Force.com IDE

Tags: custom-object, package, xml, force.com-ide

I have one force.com project with 2 new custom object to be created in the server.
xmls for these objects like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>


    <description>This object will contain the targets that a KOL must accomplish in a KOL plan</description>
<enableActivities>false</enableActivities>
<enableBulkApi>true</enableBulkApi>
<enableFeeds>false</enableFeeds>
<enableHistory>true</enableHistory>
<enableReports>true</enableReports>
<enableSharing>true</enableSharing>
<enableStreamingApi>true</enableStreamingApi>
```

KOL Goal
 KOL Goals
     
        TR-{0000000}
        KOL Goal Name
        false
        AutoNumber
    
     ControlledByParent

and
package.xml is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>KOL_Goal_TPI__C</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Stakeholder_in_KOL_Plan_TPI__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

at package xml level it is throwing error : `cvc-elt.1 cannot find the declaration of element 'package'`

Comment: your xml seems to be fine.  can you update this question with your build.xml as well?

Comment: Try putting the declaration of `<members>KOL_Goal_TPI__C</members>` and `<members>Stakeholder_in_KOL_Plan_TPI__c</members>` in the same `<types>` node, along with the `<name>CustomObject</name>. I don't think the XML will like having two `types` of the same `name`.

Comment: I'm having this issue with the IDE as well. I am using Mars version of Eclipse. Did you ever figure out the solution?